# R Weka J48 Decision Tree Cannot handle numeric class

Tags: r, weka, decision-tree

I found this document on the web:
https://www.erpublication.org/admin/vol_issue1/upload%20Image/IJETR032129.pdf

There it uses on page 4 to build a decision tree with RWeka package and J48 function in R. In his example, he has both numerical and categorical values.

So, I made a test, with just on column trying to predict the other. Here is a sample:

```
VALUE CHURNED_F
    2         1
    2         0
    2         0
    2         0
    2         0
    1         0
```

This is my code:

```
m2 <- J48(`CHURNED_F` ~ ., data = head(train[, -c(1)]))
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in .jcall(o, "Ljava/lang/Class;", "getClass") : 
  weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.trees.j48.C45PruneableClassifierTree: Cannot handle numeric class!
```

I don't understand the error, first of all it is a categorical class. Second, in the example in the document it perfectly uses both categorical and numerical columns.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J48 requires the class be categorical, or in the case of R, a factor.  I believe that your "Churned_F" variable is numeric.  You can check what type your variables are by using the structure function:

```
str(train)
```

The code below allows you to build a J48 tree.  Here I ensure "CHURNED_F" is a factor.

```
library(RWeka)
train <- data.frame(VALUE = c(2,2,2,2,2,1), CHURNED_F = factor(c(1,0,0,0,0,0)))
m2 <- J48(CHURNED_F ~., data = train)
```

Comment: Thanks, with this it worked: train[,3] = factor(train[,3]) but now I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: you might try this to increase the heap size... I haven't tested it though http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/726

Answer (score 1):

It means, that your answer column must be represented by a character instead of a numeric value.  You can change it with this method:

```
Wine$X1=factor(Wine$X1,levels = c(1,2,3),labels = c("Uno","Dos","Tres"))
```

`Wine` is my data set.  `X1` is my answer column.  1, 2 and 3 are the answers.  Uno, Dos and Tres are the wanted answer after the parsing of the numeric values.